# Which character has traveled in time the most on-screen?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel

The title says it all: **Which main *Star Trek* character has traveled through time the most number of times on-screen?**  I'm referring to characters from the 22nd century to the 24th century - no 26th/29th/31st century time travelers please!  Also, only canon instances apply.

Comment: It's Doctor Who.

Comment: Janeway and crew have traveled 14 billion years back in time.

Comment: @anaranjada yes, that's correct; the question has now been clarified

Comment: @anaranjada now it does.  But I still like your answer, so I'd leave it up if I were you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a list of all the instances of time travel involving regular bridge characters:

- *TOS* 'The Naked Time' x2 - Crew of the *USS Enterprise*
- *TOS* 'Tomorrow is Yesterday' x3 - Crew of the *USS Enterprise*
- *TOS* 'The City on the Edge of Forever' x2 - McCoy, Spock and Kirk
- *TOS* 'Assignment Earth' x2 - Crew of the *USS Enterprise*
- *TOS* 'All Our Yesterdays' x2- McCoy, Spock and Kirk
- *Star Trek IV* x2 - Crew of *HMS Bounty*
- *Star Trek Generations* - Kirk and Picard
- *Star Trek First Contact* x2 - Crew of *USS Enterprise-E*
- *TNG* 'We'll Always have Paris' - Crew of *USS Enterprise-D*
- *TNG* 'Time Squared' - Picard
- *TNG* 'Yesterday's Enterprise' x1 - Tasha Yar
- *TNG* 'Cause and Effect' x4 - Crew of *USS Enterprise-D*'
- *TNG* 'Time's Arrow Pt 1 & 2' x2- Data, Picard, Riker, Troi, La Forge, Crusher
- *TNG* 'All Good Things' x? - Picard
- *DS9* 'Past Tense Pt 1 & 2' - Bashir (x2), Dax (x2), Sisko (x2), Nerys (x8), O'Brien (x8)
- *DS9* 'Visionary' x12 - O'Brien
- *DS9* 'The Visitor' x7 - Sisko
- *DS9* 'Little Green Men' x2- Nog, Odo, Quark, Rom
- *DS9* 'Trials and Tribble-ations' x2 - Crew of *USS Defiant*
- *DS9* 'Children of Time' x1 - Crew of *USS Defiant*
- *DS9* 'Wrongs Darker than Death or Night' x2 - Nerys
- *DS9* 'Time's Orphan' x4 - Molly O'Brien
- *VOY* 'Parallax' x1 - Torres and Janeway
- *VOY* 'Time and Again' x1 - Torres and Paris
- *VOY* 'Death Wish' x2 - Crew of *USS Voyager*
- *VOY* 'Future's End Pt 1 & 2' x2 - Crew of *USS Voyager*
- *VOY* 'Before and After' x12 - Kes
- *VOY* 'Relativity' - Seven (x6) and Janeway (x4)
- *VOY* 'Fury' x1 - Kes
- *VOY* 'Shattered' - Chakotay (x16), Janeway (x10), Paris (x1), Kim (x1), Torres (x1), Seven (x1), Icheb (x1), Naomi Wildman (x1)
- *VOY* 'Endgame Pt I' - Janeway
- *ENT* 'Shockwave Pt 1 & 2' x3 - Archer
- *ENT* 'Future Tense' - Tucker (x2), Reed (x4), Archer (x2)
- *ENT* 'Carpenter Street' x2 - Archer and T'Pol
- *ENT* 'Azati Prime' x2 - Archer
- *ENT* 'E Squared' x1 - Crew of *USS Enterprise NX-01*
- *ENT* 'Zero Hour' - Archer (x3), Crew of *USS Enterprise NX-01*
- *ENT* 'Stormfront' x1 - Crew of *USS Enterprise NX-01*

[Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_travel_episodes)

## And the winner is...

Chief Miles O'Brien, with an incredible **27** instances of time travel in *TNG* 'We'll Always Have Paris' and 'Cause and Effect' and then *DS9* 'Past Tense', 'Visionary', 'Trials and Tribble-ations' and 'Children of Time'!  Followed closely by Janeway and Chakotay (19 instances each)

Comment: @anaranjada well, technically it was just he head that waited in the past - the decapitated body of Data travelled in time, so I'm counting that as Data ;)  It doesn't really matter in the scheme of the question though

Comment: Jeez Miles. Pretty adventurous career for a transporter/maintenance engineer :)

Comment: Wait: Wasn't the Bounty just a holodeck simulation? Not actual time travel?

Comment: @MahatmaRandy unless you think all of that movie was in a holodeck, then no

Comment: I think Picard's final number should be quantified, namely confirming all the times in All Good Things (don't forget going to/from primordial earth). Not sure if it eclipses Mile's mileage though. Also, doesn't Q send Picard back/forth through time in *Tapestry*?

Comment: @iMerchant I didn't quantify All Good Things because it's difficult to figure that out. Regarding Tapestry, Picard expressed doubts about actually travelling in time

Comment: @N_Soong - Yet Q asserted that isn't one of his fantasies and Picard was really traveling back and forth in time. Whether he believed it or not, he was free to alter history or not.

Comment: Chief O'Brien may as well be the Doctor's next companion, since he is so used to time travel :-)

Comment: You should at least mention that it might be Picard in your conclusion, but we cannot confirm his total.

Comment: Also the crew of the Enterprise (including Picard and presumably O'Brian) traveled back in time ~10-15 minutes at the end of *Timescape*

Comment: Actually earlier in *Timescape*, the crew of the *Enterprise-D* (sans Picard, Data, LaForge, & Troi) traveled back a few seconds when the warp core breach destroyed the *Enterprise-D".